# Quasiquote interpret tree content instead of taking as literal

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-quasiquotes

Can you please explain why the two usages of Scala quasiquote below give different output between `result1` and `result2`? Is it possible to reproduce `result3` using quasiquote? i.e parse a string **content** and evaluate it?

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

val miniSrc = "val lst = (1 to 5).toList ; val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(_ + _); sum"

val tree1 = q"$miniSrc"
//tree1: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = "val lst = (1 to 5).toList ; val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(_ + _); sum"

val tree2 = q"val lst = (1 to 5).toList ; val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(_ + _); sum"
//tree2: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree =
//{
//  val lst = 1.to(5).toList;
//  val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2)));
//  sum
//}

val tb = scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val result1 = tb.eval(tree1)
//result1: Any = val lst = (1 to 5).toList ; val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(_ + _); sum

val result2 = tb.eval(tree2)
//result2: Any = 15

val result3 = tb.eval(tb.parse(miniSrc))
//result3: Any = 15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can you please explain why the two usages of Scala quasiquote below give different output between `result1` and `result2`?

`miniSrc` is a literal `String` and not a `Tree`. `q"{$miniSrc}"` *lifts* `miniSrc`, a literal `String` into another `Tree`. Lifting does not parse arbitrary code into a `Tree`, it simply splices together trees or other types into trees. `tree1` is therefore a `Tree` that contains a literal `String`.

This example ought to illustrate well enough why lifting a literal string into a tree shouldn't involve any parsing:

```
scala> val miniSrc = "abc"
miniSrc: String = abc

scala> val tree1 = q"$miniSrc"
tree1: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree = "abc"
```

`tree2` is inherently different because you are creating the `Tree` directly with the quasiquotes interpolator. Therefore, `result1` is just a literal string, but `result2` is the result of some executed code within `tree2`.

> Is it possible to reproduce `result3` using quasiquotes? i.e parse a string content and evaluate it?

No, that's what parsing is for. If you want to lift arbitrary code as a string literal into quasiquotes, you *must* parse it into a `Tree` first. Otherwise, it will just be a literal.

```
scala> val tree1 = q"${tb.parse(miniSrc)}"
tree1: tb.u.Tree =
{
  val lst = 1.to(5).toList;
  val sum = lst.foldLeft(0)(((x$1, x$2) => x$1.$plus(x$2)));
  sum
}
```

Not that when working with macros, you can parse using the macro's `Context`. That is, `c.parse` (instead of using `ToolBox`).